# How to redirect output to a file which name is the current date and time?

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like to redirect the output of a command (in the Windows command line) to a file which name is the current date and time. For example:

```
my_path\mysqldump.exe my_database_name > auto_generated_file_name
```

where `auto_generated_file_name` should be something like `2010_09_30___11_41_58.txt`.

This command will automatically run from time to time. This is the reason I need the file name to be **automatically** generated.

What is the easiest method to achieve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following command creates a blank file with the expected filename:

```
> type nul > %date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%__%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.txt

> dir /b
2010_09_29__22_12_44.txt
```

You can use the part after `type nul >` in place of your `auto_generated_file_name`.

Comment: Problem is that this depends heavily on your locale - For me it produced: `017_0._1.__10_41_13.txt`

Comment: Using `%time:~0,2%` adds a space to your file name in the morning. Quote the filename in your command to tell Windows that's OK.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [nice solution here](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-16514-batch-file-for-one-current-date-in-text-file), and it almost matches your example formatting:

```
set dd = %date% %Time% 
my_command > MyFile__%dd:~0,2%_%dd:~3,2%_%dd:~6,4%___%dd:~11,2%_%dd:~14,2%.txt
```

Output: "MyFile__22_05_2009__6_20.txt"

Comment: set: Variable name must begin with a letter